# CountVectorizer returning zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have a vocabulary text file where each line is a word. Few words from vocabulary are shown below:

```
AccountsAndTransactions_/get/v2/accounts/details_DELETE
AccountsAndTransactions_/get/v2/accounts/details_GET
AccountsAndTransactions_/get/v2/accounts/details_POST
AccountsAndTransactions_/get/v2/accounts/{accountId}/transactions_DELETE
AccountsAndTransactions_/get/v2/accounts/{accountId}/transactions_GET
AccountsAndTransactions_/get/v2/accounts/{accountId}/transactions_POST
```

Important: `AccountsAndTransactions_/get/v2/accounts/details_DELETE` this is a single word in this problem.

Reading vocabulary from text file:

```py
with open(Path(VOCAB_FILE), "r") as f:
    vocab = f.read().splitlines()
```

Generating `doc_paths`:

```py
doc_paths = [f for f in listdir(DOC_DIR) if isfile(join(DOC_DIR, f))]
r = re.compile(".*txt")
doc_paths = list(filter(r.match, doc_paths))
doc_paths = [Path(join(DOC_DIR, i)) for i in doc_paths]
```

I am running `CountVectorizer` on documents.

```py
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input='filename', lowercase=False, vocabulary=vocab)
tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(doc_paths) # doc_paths is list of pathlib.Path(...) object.
X = tf.toarray() # returns zero matrix
```

The issue is all the values in `X` are zero. (The corpus-documents are not empty.)

Could someone help me? I want the term frequency of every word in vocabulary for each document.

Comment: Where are you specifying the list of files to read?  `fit_transform` expects a list of strings, not a list of filenames.

Comment: @TimRoberts Not when `input=="filename"`.

Comment: What is `vocab`? I cannot reproduce the problem with the given sample

Comment: When input argument to CountVectorizer is "filename" then data is first read from file, so you provide filenames.

Comment: `vocab` is the vocabulary, a few words from the vocabulary are shown above.

Comment: So what you _want_ is to just count the exact matchings of `vocab`? Because of `token_pattern`, you won't get such exact matching.

Comment: @Chris Yes, I want the term frequency of every word in vocabulary for each document. I don't know about `token_pattern`. Please fill me in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236337/discussion-between-chris-and-kaushal-kishore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by overriding default `analyzer` of `CountVectorizer`:

```py
def analyzer_custom(doc):
    return doc.split()

tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input='filename',
                                lowercase=False,
                                vocabulary=vocab,
                                analyzer=analyzer_custom)
```

Thanks to @Chris for explaining internal details of CountVectorizer.